# Bash - 3 infinite while loops in parallel

Tags: bash, shell

I have 3 scripts that send some metrics:

- `script1.sh` takes ~1s to execute
- `script2.sh` takes ~10s to execute
- `script3.sh` takes ~2min to execute

I want to send metrics from `script1.sh` and `script2.sh` every ~30s and from `script3.sh` as soon as possible (there can be only one instance of this script running at a time). In other words, to parallelize 3 `while` loops:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
    ./script1.sh
    sleep 30
done

while true; do
    ./script2.sh
    sleep 20
done

while true; do
    ./script3.sh
done
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but try running each loop in a separate backgrounded subshell

```bsh
( while true; do ./script1.sh; sleep 30; done ) &
( while true; do ./script2.sh; sleep 20; done ) &
( while true; do ./script3.sh;           done ) &
wait
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about spawning subshells. Will remember this one :)